# getFromDirectory not working in a akka-http route

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a folder `root` that contains a `index.html` and other resources such as `.css` files.

Now, I am trying to host this folder at `localhost:8080/test` using the akka-http route (`myRoute`) below. Additionally, I want to host a hello-world page at `localhost:8080`. I'd also like the URIs with a trailing slash to redirect to the non-slashed URIs (`localhost:8080/test` should be equal to `localhost:8080/test/`).

Somehow I am unable to achieve this. The hello-world page is working correctly, but the folder is not hosted. All I get is a `The requested resource could not be found.` message (in Chrome).

```scala
def route: Route = {
  redirectToNoTrailingSlashIfPresent(StatusCodes.Found) {
    (pathSingleSlash {
      get {
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, homeHtml)) // "hello world"
      }
    }
    ~
      pathPrefix("test") {
           getFromDirectory("root") // contains the index.html
    })
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

When I try to use `getFromFile(webDir + "/index.html")` instead of `getFromDirectory(webDir)` (`webDir` being `root`) the `index.html` is loaded but cannot access the css/js files.

Comment: Could you try putting `pathEndOrSingleSlash` inside `pathPrefix("test")`. Also replace `pathSingleSlash` with `pathEndOrSingleSlash` for root route(which displays `hello world`) for better pattern matching.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this did not have any effect on the result. And the docs are stating that using `redirectToNoTrailingSlashIfPresent` is the preferred way (even though I am not sure I'm using int correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved `redirectToTrailingSlashIfMissing` to inner directive. It seems it does what you want. Please note that `webdir` is absolute path to the folder with `index.html`

```
val webdir = "/Users/<your_absolute_path>/root"
  val homeHtml = "homeHtml"
  def route =
    concat(
      pathSingleSlash {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, homeHtml)) // "hello world"
        }
      },
      (get & pathPrefix("test")) {
        (pathEndOrSingleSlash & redirectToTrailingSlashIfMissing(StatusCodes.TemporaryRedirect)) {
          getFromFile(s"$webdir/index.html")
        } ~ {
          getFromDirectory(webdir)
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: Nice, that works. (`webdir` can be a relative path as well)